# angular Looping through an array in typescript file

Tags: angular

I have a component.service that returns Json

```
export interface ILocations {

    LocationID: string;
    LocationName: string;

}
```

service

```
getUserLocations(UserID: string):Observable<ILocations[]> {
    return this._http.get(environment.BASE_API_URL + 'GetUserLocations/' + UserID)
        .map((response: Response) => <ILocations[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Json printed from console:

```
All {
  "result": [
    {
      "LocationID": "01",
      "LocationName": "01"                             "
    },
    {
      "LocationID": "02",
      "LocationName": "01"
    }
  ]
}
```

this is my component.ts file , I am just trying to loop through the array because I need to extract `LocationID` in on string that are separated by comma. For example (seeing the above json) I will need to have a string looks like this

```
location: string;
location= '01,02'
```

I think my array is not loaded and I tried to double check the values but I get errors. not sure what I am missing ,this is how I subscribe to the service

```
  locations: ILocations[] = null;

    ngOnInit(): void {

        console.log("id : " + this.userID)
        this.GetUserLocations(this.userID)

        for (let location of this.locations) {
            console.log('code ' + location.LocationID.toString());
       }//this is causing error

    }

    GetUserLocations(PNSLUID: string) {

        this._dashboardService.getUserLocations(PNSLUID)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.locations = data;
                console.log('location ' + this.locations[0].LocationID);//this is causing error 
            },
            error => console.log('GetControls Method: ' + <any>error, 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
```

*******************************UPDATE******************************************************************
Changed my service

```
getUserLocations(UserID: string){


    return this._http.get(environment.BASE_API_URL + 'GetUserLocations/' + UserID)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

component.ts ( only returns the first raw?)

```
  locations: ILocations[] = null;

    ngOnInit(): void {


        this.GetUserLocations(this.userID)


    }

    GetUserLocations(PNSLUID: string) {

        this._dashboardService.getUserLocations(PNSLUID)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.locations = data.result;

                for (let location of this.locations) {
                    console.log('code ' + location.LocationID.toString());
                }//this is returning only the first raw.
            },

            error => console.log('GetControls Method: ' + <any>error, 'alert alert-danger'));




}
```

Comment: Why would you loop through the locations onInit by assigning null value to it, locations: ILocations[] = null; also if you console data inside data => {
                this.locations = data;
                console.log('location ' + this.locations[0].LocationID);//this is causing error 
            }  then do you get All {
  "result": [
    {
      "LocationID": "01",
      "LocationName": "01"                             "
    },
    {
      "LocationID": "02",
      "LocationName": "01"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: my for loop is failing see above code section update

Comment: what do you see if you console data.result inside GetUserLocations

Comment: I only see one row 'Code 0' i should get two rows

Comment: try ngOnChanges instead of ngOnInit life cycle hook

Comment: I found my issue , the above code is working ..no need for ngOnChanges..it was something I overlooked in my code ..my bad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two mistakes

1. In your service method getUserLocations

Modify the map method to only return json liek below

```
  getUserLocations(UserID: string):Observable<ILocations[]> {
        return this._http.get(environment.BASE_API_URL + 'GetUserLocations/' + UserID)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

2. And then in  GetUserLocations,Because you are getting relevant data in "result", see the console.log output that you posted earlier.

   GetUserLocations(PNSLUID: string) {

   ```
       this._dashboardService.getUserLocations(PNSLUID)
           .subscribe(
           data => {
               this.locations = data.result;  //**Notice result here**
               console.log('location ' + this.locations[0].LocationID);//this is causing error 
           },
           error => console.log('GetControls Method: ' + <any>error, 'alert alert-danger'));
   }
   ```

   This will solve the issue hopefully :)

Comment: Thanks you pointed me to the right direction, however, my for loop is failing see above code section update

Comment: @rgoal :
for (let location of this.locations) {
                    console.log('code ' + location.UserID.toString());
                }//this is returning only the first raw.
But userID is not a member of location interface? Is it a typo? also what error do you see in console after first row.

Comment: yes, it was a type..i updated my code..not sure why for loop is not working properly and it is throwing an error if it is insidie ngOntInt

Comment: If is inside `ngOnInt` your are experimenting a **race condition**, the call to the server is made asyncronously, so the code execute the `for` loop before the data arrive from the server. You should run your `for` loop inside the suscribe.

Comment: make sense ...updated code..however, when i put it inside subscribe I only get the first row?

Comment: Thank you all, above code is working ...i overlooked something in my code from another component.